# Foreach duplicando dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, foreach

Possuo 2 `foreachs`, para fazer uma busca de datas em `ViewBags`, onde eu retorno ambos em um select.

Porém para cada item do primeiro foreach, ele faz um loop completo no segundo, assim duplicando os valores, por cada item do primeiro.

Ex: Caso eu tenha 3 itens no primeiro `foreach` e 2 itens no segundo, meu resultado final será de 6 itens no meu `select`, sendo que ele repete dos dados, após o *loop* do primeiro.

Meu problema é: Como fazer para não repetir esses dados?

Meus Foreahcs na view:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                        <select class="form-control" style="width:250px" id="selectPeriodo" name="sAquisitivo">
                            @foreach (var date in ViewBag.Ferias)
                            {
                                foreach (var fim in ViewBag.FimFerias)
                                {
                                    <option>
                                        @Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToShortDateString() à @Convert.ToDateTime(fim).ToShortDateString()
                                    </option>
                                }
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Minhas ViewBags:

```
 ViewBag.Ferias = funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato && r.DtInicioConcessao == null)
            .Select(x => x.DtInicioPeriodo).ToList();
            ViewBag.FimFerias = funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato && r.DtInicioConcessao == null)
            .Select(x => x.DtFimPeriodo).ToList();
```

Entidade:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? dtInicioFerias { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? dtFimFerias { get; set; }

        public string sAquisitivo { get; set; }
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado atual]

Lembrando que estou trabalhando com Foreachs, pois foi a única opção que consegui encontrar para formatar as datas par ao formato dd/MM/yyyy. Pois elas em um DropDownList não vinha formatado, mesmo usando o toString() e adicionando anotações no model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme colocado pelo @Maniero, a *view* deve ter o mínimo de processamento possível, o ideal é você simplesmente exibir o valor na *view* e não ficar convertendo dados etc...

Considere o código abaixo apenas caso você não consiga implementar como o @Maniero sugeriu. Porém focando no seu problema do `foreach`, acredito que você pode tentar montar esses valores sem duplicar as datas assim:

```
...
@for(int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Ferias.Count(); i++)
{
   var l = 0;
   while(l < 1)
   {
      <option>
              @Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.Ferias[i]).ToShortDateString() à @Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.FimFerias[i]).ToShortDateString()
       </option>
      l++;
   }
}
...
```

---

**Edição:**

Removido o parênteses de `ViewBag.Ferias.Count` no `for`.

Removido o `While`, eu havia inserido ele no código acima quando estava raciocinando sobre os 2 `foreach`s, mas ele não é necessário.

```
...
@for(int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Ferias.Count; i++)
{
      <option>
              @Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.Ferias[i]).ToShortDateString() à @Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.FimFerias[i]).ToShortDateString()
       </option>
}
...
```

Comment: eu teste seu método, e obtenho esse erro: O membro não invocável 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime?>.Count' não pode ser usado como um método.
Eu estou tentando tratar no controle, mas tenho que exibir para meus superiores aprovarem a funcionalidade, então adicionei na view, apenas para isso.

Comment: Provavelmente é o () do ViewBag.Ferias.Count(). Teste retirando o () por favor. Se for esse o problema eu atualizo o código da resposta.

Comment: Foi exatamente isso. Obrigado
Agora vou trabalhar para tratar no controller, tirando da view o método.

Comment: Apenas uma nota, este laço while é desnecessario.

Comment: `var l = 0; while(l < 1) { /**/ l++; }`? [Vou comecar a fazer isso em torno de todo o meu codigo........](https://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html)

Comment: @user2363 removido o While, eu havia inserido ele no código quando estava raciocinando sobre os 2 foreachs, mas havia esquecido de remover na resposta, realmente ele não é necessário. Valeu!

Comment: @dcastro removido o While, eu havia inserido ele no código acima quando estava raciocinando sobre os 2 foreachs, mas ele não é necessário. Valeu!

Comment: @Renilson Andrade que bom que ajudou. Atualizei a resposta conforme seu retorno e colaboração do user2363 e dcastro.

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi como esta resposta isoladamente responde a pergunta.

Comment: @bigown minha pergunta foi pelos dados duplicados, por causa dos 2 foreachs, tirando os foreachs e adicionando o for( mostrado acimda), os dados pararam de duplicar, e estão mostrando normalmente, solucionando o problema que tinha. Por isso marquei como resposta.

Comment: @bigown os valores estavam sendo exibidos de forma duplicada certo? É possível resolver isso tanto realizando o ajuste conforme a sua resposta (que eu inclusive cito na minha resposta como melhor forma). Mas, com esse ajuste usando "for" também resolve o problema. Entendeu?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade sem mudar nada na *viewbag*?

Comment: Sim, deixando do mesmo jeito que estava

Comment: Me parece estranho, mas não tenho como testar. De qualquer forma gerar a forma que este algoritmo está feito desde a *viewbag*, até a *view* está fundamentalmente errado. Ele pode até dar o resultado que você espera mas do jeito errado. Não é assim que se programa. Mas a decisão é sua e o prejuízo não será meu.

Comment: @bigown Tem algum problema no código da minha resposta?

Comment: Tem problema no código original, o seu só o mantém. Continua tratando duas expressões relacionadas como se fossem coisas separadas. E ainda, embora seja provável que funcione, nada garante que as duas expressões estejam sincronizadas e é possível imprimir datas de início e fim que não estão relacionadas. Você não pode confiar em uma coleção para varear outra. Funciona, mas isto é programação por coincidência. Programação por coincidência é um problema grave e endêmico mas só quem não pratica esta forma entende isto.

Comment: Blz se minha resposta está ok, ótimo! Eu entendi e concordo 100% com seu comentário tbm. Meu código foca resolver o problema de duplicidade no loop. Agora, qual a melhor forma ou mais correta de se fazer para renderizar uma lista no cenário passado... já seria outra pergunta, onde sua resposta se encaixa sem sombra de dúvidas.

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que é isto que você quer. Não vejo nenhuma razão para existir dois `foreach`s. Esta solução foi dada porque a `viewBag` foi criada de forma errada. Então ela ficaria assim:

```
ViewBag.Ferias = funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato && r.DtInicioConcessao == null)
        .Select(x => new { Inicio = x.DtInicioPeriodo, Fim = x.DtFimPeriodo}).ToList();
```

Eu fiz a conversão aí mas você pode não fazer, se precisar do dado sem conversão em outro lugar. Mas em geral não é o correto, a *view* deve ter o mínimo de processamento possível. Então a *view* ficará assim:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <select class="form-control" style="width:250px" id="selectPeriodo" name="sAquisitivo">
        @foreach (var date in ViewBag.Ferias) {
            <option>
                @Convert.ToDateTime(date.Inicio).ToShortDateString() à @Convert.ToDateTime(date.Fim).ToShortDateString()
            </option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/Selecting.cs).

Eu não tenho como testar, talvez você tenha que fazer alguma adaptação para funcionar mas a ideia geral é esta.

Comment: Eu já tentei desta forma, mas quando eu coloco ao convert na ViewBag, eu recebo esse erro: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
Editei a pergunta, com a entidade.

Comment: Se é só este o problema, seria só mudar a conversão de lugar novamente, vou editar. Eu estou achando estranho toda a expressão, mas se você está dizendo que funciona, ok. Como eu disse, não tenho como testar. Não entendo porque pegar um tipo `DateTime` tenha que ser convertido para `DateTime`. E não entendo porque funciona na *view* mas não na *viewbag*. Mas seu problema era ter dois *loops*. Este problema foi resolvido.